# Java EE 7 Timer Service Performance on Glassfish 4.1

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-ee-7, glassfish-4.1

In a project I am working currently on, I have to read data from a number of devices using modbus/ethernet but the user has to configure at what time he/she wants the system to do the reading. 
So I was thinkig about using Timer Service to programatically create a timer every time the user adds a reading configuration. The problem is that the user can configure as many "timers" as he/she wants.
So my question is, would this approach affect the application server performance? I'm using Glassfish 4.1, java 8 and java EE 7.

Comment: How many timers are we talking about here? Is the application server responsible for other jobs? What performance issues are you worried about, exactly? Timers firing at the wrong time? Out of memory errors? It's hard to imagine a few dozen user-created timers causing problems, unless TimerService is grossly inefficient. Fairly easy to test though: just programmatically create a few hundred of thousand timers and run it.

Comment: @DavidS I'm dong some tests, I just wanted to get a second opinion. Thanks for your comments.